# How to find Api key ID with Event Webhook

Tags: sendgrid

We have almost 30 API Keys that we distributed among developers so their apps can send emails through SendGrid. How can I find which API Key has been used for a certain message? I try with an Event Webhook, but nowhere in the resulting json is the API Key.

Comment: I'm not sure, just checking with the SendGrid team to find out!

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the team and they said that the API key is logged, but it is not returned as part of any API response or within the Event Webhook.

However, you can [use the Email Activity API to request emails by `api_key_id`](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api#query-reference). So if you have your developers’ API key IDs you can find the emails that they have sent.

Comment: Is there a way to force the developers to submit the API KeyID as a custom argument? That is to make them unable to send messages unless they include it.

Comment: I’m on my phone, so can’t update this properly right now, but someone did give me a better solution for this. Will get back to you when I can!

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a look, hope that helps.

Comment: It looks like I need both the API Key and the associated API KeyID to make the query. Or do I simply need one API Key with turned on "Email Activity" with which I can authorize and query all emails for all other API Keys? Both ways I'll need the API KeyIDs which I don't have since we don't keep track of them. Probably some can be found but most will have to be recreated. But the bigger problem is to convince the client to pay for this feature. It's cheap and they'll probably agree but it's a government client and I'll have to waste many hours, which I won't. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: You only need one api key and the list of api key IDs to perform this search. You can retrieve the API key IDs with this API: https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/api-keys/retrieve-all-api-keys-belonging-to-the-authenticated-user

Comment: When I compose the request I get an error "access forbidden" so it may work after we purchase Additional Email Activity History. And since I got your attention, I'll ask one more thing - is there an option to implement an alarm if total daily requests surpass a certain amount? E.g. if we have 20K requests today and it's more than 5K, to receive an email. Is there a native way or I should play with Event Webhooks?